# Python Check item exists in line while iterating through list

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am trying to loop through two lists and only want to print an item if it DOES exist in the second list. I will be doing this through very large files so do not want to store them in memory like a list or dictionary. Is there a way I can do this without storing into a list or dict?

I am able to do the below to confirm they are NOT in the list but unsure why it is not working when I am trying confirm they ARE in the list by removing the "not".

Code to verify item DOES NOT exist in list_2.

```
list_1 = ['apple',
          'pear',
          'orange',
          'kiwi',
          'strawberry',
          'banana']

list_2 = ['kiwi',
          'melon',
          'grape',
          'pear']

for fruit_1 in list_1:
    if all(fruit_1 not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2):
        print(fruit_1)
```

Code to verify item DOES exist in list_2.

```
list_1 = ['apple',
          'pear',
          'orange',
          'kiwi',
          'strawberry',
          'banana']

list_2 = ['kiwi',
          'melon',
          'grape',
          'pear']

for fruit_1 in list_1:
    if all(fruit_1 in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2):
        print(fruit_1)
```

Comment: Can't you just use list comprehension? `[x for x in list_1 if x in list_2]`, would return a list of the items in `list_1` if they're in `list_2`. And inversely `[x for x in list_1 if x not in list_2]`.

Comment: @MBatish if you accept to save _one_ list in memory, then you can create a set with that list, and iterate on the other one (reading a file). That will be fast. Else it will take forever.

Comment: Okay using the all() function I am avoiding that. Just confused as to why the inverse is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to create memory mapped files:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = pd.read_csv('list1.txt', dtype=str, header=None, memory_map=True)
list2 = pd.read_csv('list2.txt', dtype=str, header=None, memory_map=True)

exists = pd.merge(list1, list2, how='inner', on=0)
for fruit in exists[0].tolist():
    print fruit
```

The `list1.txt` and `list2.txt` files contain the strings from the question with one string on each line.

**Output**

```
pear
kiwi
```

I do not have any really large files to experiment with, so I do not have any performance measurements.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how you get them:

```
exists = [item for item in list_1 if item in list_2]
does_not_exist = [item for item in list_1 if item not in list_2]
```

And to `print` them:

```
for item in exists:
    print item
for item in does_not_exist:
    print item
```

But if you want to just print:

```
for item in list_1:
    if item in list_2:
        print item
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But this is saving the output to the exists and does_does_not_exist variables. The files I am dealing with large and would like to avoid saving them to memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's sets to work out the items in both lists

```
set(list1).intersection(set(list_2))
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: "I will be doing this through very large files so do not want to store them in memory like a list or dictionary" ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the inverse by doing a True/False evaluation.

```
list_1 = ['apple',
          'pear',
          'orange',
          'kiwi',
          'strawberry',
          'banana']

list_2 = ['kiwi',
          'melon',
          'grape',
          'pear']

# DOES exist
for fruit_1 in list_1:
    if all(fruit_1 not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2) is False:
        print(fruit_1)

print('\n')

# DOES NOT exist
for fruit_1 in list_1:
    if all(fruit_1 not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2) is True:
        print(fruit_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `pandas` which works well on large-scale data.

Use pip to install it:

`pip install pandas`

And in a way you may achieve it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Index(list_1)
s2 = pd.Index(list_2)

exists = s1.intersection(s2)
does_not_exist = s1.difference(s2)
```

And now you would see the magic things if you execute `print exists`

See [Pandas Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-operations-on-index-objects)

Answer (score 0):

The problem the code is how the **all()** function is being evaluated. To break it down a bit more simply.

```
## DOES EXIST
print all('kiwi' in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in ['pear', 'kiwi'])
print all('pear' in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in ['pear', 'kiwi'])
```

Evaluates to

```
False
False
```

Inversely if you do something like this

```
#DOES NOT EXIST
print all('apple' not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in ['pear', 'kiwi'])
print all('pear' not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in ['pear', 'kiwi'])
```

Evaluates to

```
True
False
```

I can not pinpoint why this is the cause, but it may be how the **all()** function returns true **if all elements of the iterable are true** and false otherwise.

In any case I think using any() instead of all() for the DOES exist part would work.

```
print "DOES NOT EXIST"
for fruit_1 in list_1:
    # print all(fruit_1 not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2)
    if all(fruit_1 not in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2):
        print(fruit_1)

print "\nDOES EXIST"
for fruit_1 in list_1:
    if any(fruit_1 in fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2):
        print(fruit_1)

DOES NOT EXIST
apple
orange
strawberry
banana

DOES EXIST
pear
kiwi
```

Answer (score -1):

One issue with your code is that the all method [returns false if any single check returns false](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all). Another is that the `fruit_1 in fruit_2` section is checking to see if `fruit_1` is a substring of `fruit_2`. If we were to modify the lists to make your logic work they would look like:

```
list_1 = ['apple',
          'pear',
          'orange',
          'kiwi',
          'berry',
          'banana',
          'grape']

list_2 = ['grape',
          'grape',
          'grape',
          'grape',
          'grape']
```

but could be:

```
list_1 = ['apple',
          'pear',
          'orange',
          'kiwi',
          'berry',
          'banana',
          'grape']

list_2 = ['strawberry',
          'strawberry',
          'strawberry',
          'strawberry',
          'strawberry',
          'strawberry']
```

since `berry` is in `strawberry`. If we were to continue to use iteration to make this check, as opposed to an intersection of sets, [as @wrdeman suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639113/2000793), then, using the dataset you provided, it would look like this:

```
for fruit_1 in list_1:
    if fruit_1 in list_2:
        print(fruit)
```

The other modification could be to change `all` to `any`, which [returns true if any of the iterables items return true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). Then your code would look like:

```
for fruit_1 in list_1:
    if any(fruit_1 == fruit_2 for fruit_2 in list_2):
        print(fruit_1)
```